# Trying to use scrollHeight in react

Tags: reactjs, height

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting undefined when I console.log heightSet?

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.updateDimensions();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateDimensions.bind(this));
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateDimensions.bind(this));
}

updateDimensions() {
    this.setState({ heightSet: document.scrollHeight });
    console.log(document.clientHeight);
}
```

the same console.log worked for window.innerHeight (clientHeight gets undefined as well) but I don't want inner height I want scrollHeight.

thanks

Comment: oh common that ain't going to be the reason why it's undefined. there. updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scrollHeight` is a property on `Element` so I guess you maybe want `document.body.scrollHeight`.

By the way, every time you called `this.updateDimensions.bind(this)` you get a new function, so you can't use this approach to add and remove the same event listener.

You should add a constructor to your class, containing the following:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateDimensions = this.updateDimensions.bind(this);
}
```

Then you can add/remove `this.updateDimensions` directly:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.updateDimensions();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateDimensions);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateDimensions);
}

updateDimensions() {
    this.setState({ heightSet: document.body.scrollHeight });
}
```

Comment: I've added the full constructor

Comment: The other bits are now there

Comment: The main thing I can see is an increasingly complicated requirement. One immediate problem that I can see is that you're subscribing to the window resize event, which has nothing to do with adding elements to your container.

Comment: It was my assumption. after all why wouldn't it they're technically a "child" of that property in my mind. what ways could I go about solving this?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try to use the "scroll" event instead.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.updateDimensions();
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.updateDimensions);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.updateDimensions);
}

updateDimensions() {
    this.setState({ heightSet: window.scrollY });
}
```